# Changing JavaScript array values

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I've been following this [guide on w3schools to dynamically change the elements of a dropdown select based off another dropdown select](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_select_options3), as seen below:

The code to do this is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>   

<select id="car" onchange="ChangeCarList()"> 
  <option value="">-- Car --</option> 
  <option value="VO">Volvo</option> 
  <option value="VW">Volkswagen</option> 
  <option value="BMW">BMW</option> 
</select> 

<select id="carmodel"></select> 

<script>
var carsAndModels = {};
carsAndModels['VO'] = ['V70', 'XC60', 'XC90'];
carsAndModels['VW'] = ['Golf', 'Polo', 'Scirocco', 'Touareg'];
carsAndModels['BMW'] = ['M6', 'X5', 'Z3'];

function ChangeCarList() {
    var carList = document.getElementById("car");
    var modelList = document.getElementById("carmodel");
    var selCar = carList.options[carList.selectedIndex].value;
    while (modelList.options.length) {
        modelList.remove(0);
    }
    var cars = carsAndModels[selCar];
    if (cars) {
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
            var car = new Option(cars[i], i);
            modelList.options.add(car);
        }
    }
} 
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

However, I noticed that for the second dropdown select, the element's values are numbered, and I was wondering how to change those values into text.

Eg. in the linked example the first select is as follows:

```
<select id="car" onchange="ChangeCarList()"> 
  <option value="">-- Car --</option> 
  <option value="VO">Volvo</option> 
  <option value="VW">Volkswagen</option> 
  <option value="BMW">BMW</option> 
</select>
```

And if I set the value of the first select to Volvo, the second select is as follows:

```
<select id="carmodel"> 
  <option value="1">V70</option> 
  <option value="2">XC60</option> 
  <option value="3">XC90</option> 
</select>
```

What I would like to obtain compared to above:

```
<select id="carmodel"> 
  <option value="V70">V70</option> 
  <option value="XC60">XC60</option> 
  <option value="XC90">XC90</option> 
</select>
```

Comment: Where's the ChangeCarList function?

Comment: please add more details

Comment: @baao It's in the demo linked.

Comment: `value="1"` you see the quotes? That means it already is text. And even `value=1` would be just a shorthand for `value="1"`. All attributes in HTML contain text, always, it's up to whoever uses that attribute to parse/interpret that text/string.

Comment: @mistaq `It's in the demo linked` 404, doesn't work for me. Could you please include all relevant code in the question, not just linking.

Comment: I've added it to the opening post now. Also, besides ticking a working answer post, should I add the answer to the opening post as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `var car = new Option(cars[i], i)` with `var car = new Option(cars[i], cars[i])`

**DEMO :**

```js
var carsAndModels = {};
carsAndModels['VO'] = ['V70', 'XC60', 'XC90'];
carsAndModels['VW'] = ['Golf', 'Polo', 'Scirocco', 'Touareg'];
carsAndModels['BMW'] = ['M6', 'X5', 'Z3'];

function ChangeCarList() {
    var carList = document.getElementById("car");
    var modelList = document.getElementById("carmodel");
    var selCar = carList.options[carList.selectedIndex].value;
    while (modelList.options.length) {
        modelList.remove(0);
    }
    var cars = carsAndModels[selCar];
    if (cars) {
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
            var car = new Option(cars[i], cars[i]);
            modelList.options.add(car);
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<select id="car" onchange="ChangeCarList()"> 
  <option value="">-- Car --</option> 
  <option value="VO">Volvo</option> 
  <option value="VW">Volkswagen</option> 
  <option value="BMW">BMW</option> 
</select> 

<select id="carmodel"></select>
```

Comment: Mark it as a correct so that it will be useful for others also

Comment: Btw, how do you implement a demo like this in a post? This seems rather useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily using a PHP/MySQL/Ajax and store them in a database, however if you don't want to use any serverside programming, you can set a data-* global attribute for each of your option tags:
`data-option="Car model name here"`

Read more about "data-*" on W3Schools: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp

Answer (score 0):

Here are two options for you:

Change the constructor:

```
var car = new Option(cars[i], cars[i]);
```

Or

```
var car = new Option(cars[i]);
car.value = cars[i];
```

Just after the constructor.

The problem you are facing is caused by the second argument in the constructor of the `Option` object, which gives the value of the option element.